# Filter only TCP SYN segments in scapy

Tags: python, scapy

How can I filter only TCP SYN segments in Scapy?
Could someone give me a simple example, please?
I tried hard but I dont know scapy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only TCP SYN segments:

```
tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-syn != 0
```